# Partial font style modification

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a pie chart and a legend in Excel 2003.

The legend entries are composed of strings like this:

```
75% Ice Cream

20% Brownies

5% Gummy Bears
```

I am trying to put the exposure percentage in bold but leave the rest of the series name (Ice Cream, Brownies, or Gummy Bears) in regular font.

Is it possible to do this?

So far I have been working with variations on this code. In addition, I have tried using the `Split()` function on the SeriesCollection object and even recording a macro to see what Excel would generate in VBA. Thus far I can only get the text to appear in all bold, or all regular font, and not a mix of the two.

```
For x = 1 To 3
  myChartObject.Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(x).Font.Bold = True
Next x
```

Suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't catch the fact that you're working in a chart, *but* hopefully the below can help.  If you can get the characters, then you can bold certain parts of a string.  (Assuming your column A has a cell with `20% Brownies`, the next cell `75% Ice Cream`, etc.)

```
Sub boldPercent()
Dim i&, lastRow&, percentLength&, percentAmt$
Dim k&

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming your data is in column A

For i = 1 To lastRow
    percentAmt = Left(Cells(i, 1), WorksheetFunction.Search("%", Cells(i, 1)))
    percentLength = Len(percentAmt)
    With Cells(i, 1).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=percentLength)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

So perhaps you can use that and tweak it to work with the chart area?  Have VBA loop through your chart titles, and perhaps you can use the same method above.

Edit: I'm making a mock example chart to try and work on this - but how are you getting the percentages of each category into the Legend? I have set up a super simple chart, but don't know where you went from here ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU33Z.jpg))

(I'm expecting your legend to say `75% Ice Cream`, `20% Brownies`, etc. right?)

Edit2: Okay, I have moved into using the `Chart` object, hoping to grab each Legend Entry, and would feather in the bolding of characters as I did above...however, I can't get `legendString`ever to be a non-empty string:

```
Sub Bold_Legend_Text()
Dim stringToFind$
Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim legEnt As LegendEntry
Dim cht As Chart
Dim i&

Dim percentLength&
Dim legendString$

stringToFind = "%"
For Each cObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Set cht = cObj.Chart
    With cht
        If .HasLegend Then
            Debug.Print .Legend.LegendEntries.Count
            For Each legEnt In .Legend.LegendEntries
                ' This always returns an empty string, not sure why!
                legendString = legEnt.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
                Debug.Print legendString
                ' Then we'd find where "%" shows up in the Legend title, and try to bold
                ' just certain characters


            Next legEnt
        End If
Next cObj
End Sub
```

(Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237721/iterate-through-all-text-in-cells-charts-textboxes-in-excel-using-vba))

Comment: Thanks, @BruceWayne. So it really can't be done using the `SeriesCollection` object or the `LegendEntries` object. The `legEnt` variable won't ever return a string. To do this, I actually had to create shapes that resemble legend keys and add text boxes next to them that hold the info. (I used two to right-align the percentage exposure column values.) Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @DianaTortolini - Glad you found a solution for you, clever idea.